# El método Connect no funciona en codeigniter 4

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

Intenté durante mucho tiempo crear una consulta para postgresql, configuré el archivo Database.php en el marco, pero no sé qué sucedió, lo que no funciona la consulta.

> Database.php

```
   public $default = [
    'DSN'      => 'pgsql:host=127.0.0.1;port=5432;dbname=mascotas',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'postgres',
    'password' => 'admin',
    'database' => 'mascotas',
    'DBDriver' => 'PostgreSQL',
    'DBPrefix' => '',
    'pConnect' => false,
    'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cacheOn'  => false,
    'cacheDir' => '',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swapPre'  => '',
    'encrypt'  => false,
    'compress' => false,
    'strictOn' => false,
    'failover' => [],
    'port'     => 5432,
];
```

Este es mi archivo Database.php en Config de Codeigniter 4

> Registro.php controlador

```
public function formulario_registro()
{
    $db = \Config\Database::connect(); // Problemas con este metodo Connect
}
```

En el navegador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi navegador, cuando llamo al método `$db= \Config\Database::connect();` Recibo ese error de Whoops, no sé qué estoy haciendo mal, ya configuré el archivo Database.php y sigo la documentación oficial

Realmente sé lo que está mal en mi código, lo que necesito o lo que pasó

Necesito poder hacer cualquier tipo de consulta en la base de datos postgresql, he intentado conectarme usando la documentación oficial de codeigniter 4, sin embargo, obtengo ese error en el navegador cuando llamo a ese método `$db= \Config\Database::connect();`

No sé por qué obtengo eso, y no puedo tener éxito en la consulta postgresql

Básicamente, necesito poder hacer consultas en postgresql y recibo este error

Comment: Puedes intentar usar el verbose de los output de los errores para poder saber bien que está pasando exactamente

Comment: He cambiado a postgresql 12.4, estaba usando el pg 13 last version. Creo que codeigniter 4 no esta optimizado para pg 13 y funciona en pg 12